# knitr's spin(): cannot embed inline R expression in a heading

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm using [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/)'s [spin()](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/stitch/) function to render an R script to HTML (using RStudio's "Compile Notebook" command).

While it's easy to include a dynamic R expression in plain text, this apparently does not work for a heading.

For example, this first example correctly embeds an inline expression into plain text:

```
library(knitr)

#' You can use the special syntax {{code}} to embed inline expressions, e.g.
{{mean(x) + 2}}
#' is the mean of x plus 2.
```

But this second example, when rendering HTML, only applies the heading style to the first line ("Crosstabulation of"), and then wraps the line and reverts back to plain text:

```
library(knitr)
var0 <- "Sex"
var1 <- "Education"

#' # Crosstabulation of
{{var0}}
#' # by
{{var1}}
#' # .
```

How can I have the heading style applied to all the lines of the chunk? Is there any alternative syntax I have to use? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a limitation of `spin()`. You could pre-process the file with `brew`, or get R to output the header in markdown,

```
`%#%` <- function(tpl, vals) if(interactive()) vals else do.call(sprintf, c(fmt=tpl, vals)) 

var0 <- "Sex"
var1 <- "Education"

{{"# Crosstabulation of %s by %s " %#% list(var0, var1)}}
```

Comment: Thanks. Of course it's not fully equivalent (the {{expr}} syntax will be executed, rather than ignored, when running as a plain R script; but it definitely solves my problem.

BTW: `library(knitr)` is not needed, and the bare minimum example boils down to `{{paste0("# Crosstabulation of **",var0,"** by **", var1,"**")}}`

Comment: i've added a test for interactive() so that in a standard R session the header is not displayed